# Add commas between numbers in label and legend of ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below and I create a boxplot. I would like to format the numbers in y-axis and legend in order to have commas or .

```
df_long<-structure(list(WORDS = c("Comedy", "Education", "Entertainment", 
"Film & Animation", "Gaming", "Howto & Style", "Music", "People & Blogs", 
"Science & Technology", "Sports"), TOTALS = c(0, 943330388, 0, 
0, 0, 543234645, 45831420, 0, 27301292, 160818771)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

p <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = WORDS, y = TOTALS, fill = WORDS)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

p  +  
  theme_minimal()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, 
                                   hjust=1))+ 
  xlab("Industries") +
  ylab("Value")+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Industries"))
+
  scale_y_continuous(formatter = comma)+scale_fill_continuous(formatter = comma)
```

Comment: Do you need `scale_y_continuous(label = comma_format())`

Comment: try adding `labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)` in `scale_y_continuous` instead of `formatter = comma`

Comment: Try using `labels = comma` or `labels = scales::comma`

Comment: can someone post the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is using `scales::comma`.

Note I've removed `scale_fill_continuous` as this is incorrect: the fill aesthetic relates to a discrete variable: `WORDS`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = WORDS, y = TOTALS, fill = WORDS)) + 
  geom_boxplot()  +  
  theme_minimal()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, 
                                   hjust=1))+ 
  xlab("Industries") +
  ylab("Value")+ 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Industries")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>